# Can't get attack animation to work for arcade library with python

Tags: python, animation, arcade

I'm using a tutorial from arcade.academy and the game runs fine so far (a guy walking around collecting coins and scoring points) but I want to have an attack animation occur when the user presses Q so I can turn some of the coins into enemies and make a little RPG and increase my knowledge.

This is what I've got so far but for some reason the self.is_attacking boolean either doesn't trigger or isn't linked up properly.

Here's what I've got so far.

```
import arcade
import random
import os

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
SCREEN_TITLE = "Move with a Sprite Animation Example"

COIN_SCALE = 0.5
COIN_COUNT = 50
CHARACTER_SCALING = 1

MOVEMENT_SPEED = 5
UPDATES_PER_FRAME = 7

# Constants used to track if the player is facing left or right
RIGHT_FACING = 0
LEFT_FACING = 1


def load_texture_pair(filename):
    """
    Load a texture pair, with the second being a mirror image.
    """
    return [
        arcade.load_texture(filename, scale=CHARACTER_SCALING),
        arcade.load_texture(filename, scale=CHARACTER_SCALING, mirrored=True)
    ]


class PlayerCharacter(arcade.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):

        # Set up parent class
        super().__init__()

        # Default to face-right
        self.character_face_direction = RIGHT_FACING

        # Used for flipping between image sequences
        self.cur_texture = 0
        self.attack_texture = 0

        # Track our state
        self.jumping = False
        self.climbing = False
        self.is_on_ladder = False
        self.is_attacking = False

        # Adjust the collision box. Default includes too much empty space
        # side-to-side. Box is centered at sprite center, (0, 0)
        self.points = [[-22, -64], [22, -64], [22, 28], [-22, 28]]

        # --- Load Textures ---

        # Images from Kenney.nl's Asset Pack 3
        main_path = "images/Sprites/rogue like character/rogue like"
        # main_path = "platform_tutorial/images/Female person/PNG/Poses/character_femalePerson"
        # main_path = "platform_tutorial/images/Male person/PNG/Poses/character_malePerson"
        # main_path = "platform_tutorial/images/Male adventurer/PNG/Poses/character_maleAdventurer"
        # main_path = "platform_tutorial/images/Zombie/PNG/Poses/character_zombie"
        # main_path = "platform_tutorial/images/Robot/PNG/Poses/character_robot"

        # Load textures for idle standing
        self.idle_texture_pair = load_texture_pair(f"{main_path} idle_Animation 1_0.png")

        # Load textures for walking
        self.walk_textures = []
        for i in range(6):
            texture = load_texture_pair(f"{main_path} run_Animation 1_{i}.png")
            self.walk_textures.append(texture)

        # Load textures for attacking
        self.attack_textures = []
        for i in range(10):
            texture = load_texture_pair(f"{main_path} attack_Animation 1_{i}.png")
            self.attack_textures.append(texture)

    def update_animation(self, delta_time: float = 1/60):

        # Figure out if we need to flip face left or right
        if self.change_x < 0 and self.character_face_direction == RIGHT_FACING:
            self.character_face_direction = LEFT_FACING
        elif self.change_x > 0 and self.character_face_direction == LEFT_FACING:
            self.character_face_direction = RIGHT_FACING

        # Idle animation
        if self.change_x == 0 and self.change_y == 0:
            self.texture = self.idle_texture_pair[self.character_face_direction]
            return

        # Walking animation
        self.cur_texture += 1
        if self.cur_texture > 5 * UPDATES_PER_FRAME:
            self.cur_texture = 0
        self.texture = self.walk_textures[self.cur_texture // UPDATES_PER_FRAME][self.character_face_direction]

        # Attacking animation
        if self.is_attacking:
            self.cur_texture += 1
            if self.cur_texture > 9 * UPDATES_PER_FRAME:
                self.cur_texture = 0
                self.is_attacking = False
            self.texture = self.attack_textures[self.cur_texture // UPDATES_PER_FRAME][self.character_face_direction]


class MyGame(arcade.Window):
    # Main application class.

    def __init__(self, width, height, title):

        # Initializer

        super().__init__(width, height, title)

        # Set the working directory (where we expect to find files) to the same
        # directory this .py file is in. You can leave this out of your own
        # code, but it is needed to easily run the examples using "python -m"
        # as mentioned at the top of this program.
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        os.chdir(file_path)

        # Set up the game and initialize the variables.

        # Sprite lists
        self.player_list = None
        self.coin_list = None

        # Set up the player
        self.score = 0
        self.player = None
        self.is_attacking = False

    def setup(self):
        self.player_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.coin_list = arcade.SpriteList()

        # Set up the player
        self.score = 0
        self.player = PlayerCharacter()

        self.player.center_x = SCREEN_WIDTH // 2
        self.player.center_y = SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2
        self.player.scale = 0.8

        self.player_list.append(self.player)

        for i in range(COIN_COUNT):
            coin = arcade.AnimatedTimeSprite(scale=0.5)
            coin.center_x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH)
            coin.center_y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT)

            coin.textures = []
            coin.textures.append(arcade.load_texture("images/items/Coingold.png", scale=COIN_SCALE))
            coin.textures.append(arcade.load_texture("images/items/Coingold.png", scale=COIN_SCALE))
            coin.textures.append(arcade.load_texture("images/items/Coingold.png", scale=COIN_SCALE))
            coin.textures.append(arcade.load_texture("images/items/Coingold.png", scale=COIN_SCALE))
            coin.textures.append(arcade.load_texture("images/items/Coingold.png", scale=COIN_SCALE))
            coin.textures.append(arcade.load_texture("images/items/Coingold.png", scale=COIN_SCALE))
            coin.cur_texture_index = random.randrange(len(coin.textures))

            self.coin_list.append(coin)

        # Set the background color
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.AMAZON)

    def on_draw(self):

        # Render the screen.


        # This command has to happen before we start drawing
        arcade.start_render()

        # Draw all the sprites.
        self.coin_list.draw()
        self.player_list.draw()

        # Put the text on the screen.
        output = f"Score: {self.score}"
        arcade.draw_text(output, 10, 20, arcade.color.WHITE, 14)

    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):

        # Called whenever a key is pressed.

        if key == arcade.key.UP:
            self.player.change_y = MOVEMENT_SPEED
        elif key == arcade.key.DOWN:
            self.player.change_y = -MOVEMENT_SPEED
        elif key == arcade.key.LEFT:
            self.player.change_x = -MOVEMENT_SPEED
        elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.player.change_x = MOVEMENT_SPEED
        elif key == arcade.key.Q:
            self.is_attacking = True

    def on_key_release(self, key, modifiers):

        # Called when the user releases a key.

        if key == arcade.key.UP or key == arcade.key.DOWN:
            self.player.change_y = 0
        elif key == arcade.key.LEFT or key == arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.player.change_x = 0
        elif key == arcade.key.Q:
            self.is_attacking = False

    def on_update(self, delta_time):
        # Movement and game logic 

        self.coin_list.update()
        self.coin_list.update_animation()
        self.player_list.update()
        self.player_list.update_animation()

        # Generate a list of all sprites that collided with the player.
        hit_list = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(self.player, self.coin_list)

        # Loop through each colliding sprite, remove it, and add to the score.
        for coin in hit_list:
            coin.remove_from_sprite_lists()
            self.score += 1

def main():
    # Main method 
    window = MyGame(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)
    window.setup()
    arcade.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What have you done to try to debug this? That is a lot of code for a seemingly straightforward problem. Have you seen the page on producing a MCVE? [mcve].

Comment: No I Havnt seen that page? I was under the impression that debug only worked for errors? My code runs without a hitch through the compiler, however the animation just doesn’t run when the Q key is pressed.

Comment: I meant debugging in general, not using the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting

```
self.player.is_attacking=True
```